# What happens when you declare .autoCurry() on a function declaration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this syntax in ["Hey Underscore, You're Doing it Wrong"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA#t=255)  JavaScript talk (4:15). I would like to know what it means.

```
var add = function(x,y){
    return x + y;
}.autoCurry();//What is happening in this line.
```

Comment: If you're a beginner in JavaScript, that talk is *really* advanced material.

Comment: Yes, at 4:12 into that talk, he explicitly says that he's added "autoCurry" to the Function prototype.

Comment: Note that `autoCurry()` has been renamed to `curry()` some time ago.

Answer (score 9):

First let's looks at what curry and autocurry actually do. I've annotated the source of these two functions (originally found in the wu.js library):

```
  ////
  // Type:
  //
  //   ((a,b, ... c) -> d) -> a -> b -> ... -> c -> d
  //
  // Example:
  //
  //   function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
  //   add2 = curry(add, 2)
  //   add2(3)
  //   // 5
  function curry(fn /* variadic number of args */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    function f() { return fn.apply(this, args.concat(toArray(arguments))); }
    return f;
  }

  ////
  // Example:
  //
  //   function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
  //   autoCurry(add);
  //
  //   add(2)(3)                     
  //   // 5
  //
  //   add(2, 3) 
  //   // 5 
  function autoCurry(fn, numArgs) {
    numArgs = numArgs || fn.length;
    function f() {
      if (arguments.length < numArgs)
      {
        return numArgs - arguments.length > 0 ?
        autoCurry(curry.apply(this, [fn].concat(toArray(arguments))),
        numArgs - arguments.length) :
        curry.apply(this, [fn].concat(toArray(arguments)));
      }
      else
      {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    }
    f.toString = function() { return fn.toString(); };
    f.curried = true;
    return f;
  }
```

In other words,

```
autoCurry(add)
```

Takes a function that takes two arguments and returns a number, and returns a function A that takes a single argument and returns a function B. Where B is a function that takes a single argument and returns a number:

```
add(1) -> returns a function add1(), which itself takes a single argument.
```

Next, the speaker in that talk does the following:

```
  Function.prototype.autoCurry = function(n) { return autoCurry(this, n); }
```

This simply applies the autoCurry method to any given function (self) so that

```
var add = function(x,y){
    return x + y;
}.autoCurry();
```

Has the same effect as:

```
var add = function(x,y) { return x + y; };
add = autoCurry(add)
```

Comment: You need to have a `toArray` function defined here. As you are referring  that in defined `curry` function i.e `function toArray(args) { return [].slice.call(args); }`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't tell you what, exactly `autoCurry` is doing...  ...but what I can tell you is this:

1. They've modified the Function constructor's prototype `Function.prototype.autoCurry = function () { };`
   Every new function you make on that page will now have access to this method as one of its properties.
   `var myFunc = function () { return true; }; myFunc.autoCurry();`
2. You can chain statements together, happily in JS.
   `var myObj = { run : function () { } }, result = myObj.run();` is the same as
   `var result = { run : function () { } }.run();`, as long as you don't care about `myObj` after.

So:

1. You are creating a function, and as soon as it's created, you're running a method on it, and the return statement of that method (the last thing in the chain) is being saved to the variable.

Now, currying is a form of taking a function and wrapping it in other functions, which allows you to call it with only a portion of the arguments needed.

function add_two_numbers = function (x, y) { return x + y; }

Currying would allow you to do this:

```
var save_x_for_later = curry(add_two_numbers),
    save_y_and_add   = save_x_for_later(3),
    result = save_y_and_add(5);

result; // 8
```

As for your new title, the answer is the following:
You will get an error thrown in your face:
`.autoCurry()` is not a part of the language.
It was written, by hand, and put on the `Function.prototype` as `Function.prototype.autoCurry = function () { }`

I could go into an implementation of currying, but there's a lot of stuff to wrap your head around, if you haven't done much functional programming, or if "lambda" is a head-scratching term.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, a function instantiation expression:

```
 function name( arg1, arg2, ... ) { /* code */ }
```

creates a function and results in a reference to the function object. Thus, the `.autoCurry()` is a reference to a property on that object, which is apparently assumed to be a function.

I suspect that the example you're looking at has some other code that adds "autoCurry" to the Function prototype object. That way, every function object has access to that function as the "autoCurry" property.